# Lokalise: how to add a line break '\n'?

Tags: lokalise

I would like to add a line break wthin a string in lokalise. This is how the string looks like currently:

```
"Condition": something about this condition. "Another condition": something else about another condition.
```

This is the string I would like to be generated by lokalise in our .json file (with `\n`):

```
"Condition": something about this condition. \n"Another condition": something else about another condition.
```

However, when I add "\n" to lokalise it automatically skips the \ and generate the following string:

```
"Condition": something about this condition. \\n"Another condition": something else about another condition.
```

Is it possible to generate a line break in lokalise?

ps: I tried adding <br>, and it works at generating such a string. However, the 
 tag doesn't work as a line break in this particular scenario.

I would like to generate the following string with lokalise without editing the `.json` code itself: `"Condition": something about this condition. \n"Another condition": something else about another condition.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lokalise adds `/n` automatically when a new line is added in the text.
Adding this (with a line break in the middle) in lokalise:

```
"Condition": something about this condition.
"Another condition": something else about another condition.
```

Will generate the following under the hood:
`"Condition": something about this condition. \n"Another condition": something else about another condition.`